TSA clearance for pilot training
Hi everyone I have my tsa clearance for instrument in between my instrument I am starting my commercial training do I need to get a separate tsa clearance for that ?

This sounds like a question for [Aviation.SE].

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about travel as defined in the help center.

I was told that here a lot of tsa questions are answered

You can ask in the aviation stackexchange. TSA, in context of travel is definitely answered here.

TSA flight training clearances are not specific to a rating or endorsement. Unless your clearance specifically states that you are only allowed to use it to get an FAA instrument rating, you can use it for any flight training.
That said, take the document to the flight training school where you want to get your commercial ticket and ask them this question. They are the ones who will have to accept the document so they are the only ones who can tell you if it's good for that, or not.
